# How does the itext document divides its pages and fits elements into a page

Tags: itext

Hi I recently posted a question here :

[IText PDFImage seems to shrink or disappear during new pages after upgrade from 2.1.7 to 5.5.5 (Java .jars)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816863/itext-pdfimage-seems-to-shrink-or-disappear-during-new-pages-after-upgrade-from)

But I think it is not the problem with the library but more of a missing setting sort of problem. I am wondering if there is a way to control what element gets drawn on the existing page verses pushing to a new page

I want to do the following

-create document

-create pdfPTable

-create a bunch of image element for each PdfPCells

-add to pdfPTable then write to document

Result: It seems that some images get shrink near the end/beginng of the page or is missing ( seems like its trying to fit on to the page )

Sample code again for visibility

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = createTemporaryOutputStream();

 Document doc = newDocument();
 PdfWriter writer = newWriter(doc, baos);
 writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING | PdfWriter.PageLayoutSinglePage);

 //create page rectangle landscape
 Rectangle page = new Rectangle(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    doc.setPageSize(page);
    doc.setMargins((float)36.0, (float)36.0, (float)36.0, (float)36.0);
    doc.open();

    //create element pdf table.
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[]{(float) 770.0});
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table.setSplitRows(true);
    table.setSplitLate(false);
    table.setHeaderRows(0);

    // in my case I used 5 800*600 images (same picture) 
    //then I loop through them and create pdfcell 
    //and then add it to table which then gets added to the document
    List<Image> hi = (List<Image>) model.get("images");
    for (Image image : hi) {

        com.itextpdf.text.Image pdfImage = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(image.getBytes());
        pdfImage.scalePercent((float) (0.8642384 * 100));

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(pdfImage, false);

        table.addCell(cell);
    }

    doc.add(table);
    doc.close();
```

thank you for your time. Any insight as to what my problem is would be helpful

Comment: I suggest that you upgrade right to iText7 which is the new release :)

Comment: I'm with Alexey: if you're doing the effort of upgrading, you should upgrade to the latest version, which is indeed iText 7.0.0.

Comment: We actually already upgraded for a while and only came across the bug recently. We are hoping to resolve it in our current version and not retest our application with new the library. I am just curious as to whether this is something I can change by code or is it only on library.